# drupal validate form

Tags: drupal, forms, drupal-6, validation

I want to validate the input of a form before saving it to database to prevent Sql Injection and XSS.

I don't want to modify the code of the module directly so I've created a custom module to do this kind of stuff but I'm not exactly sure how to use the #validate element to call a validation function.

In my custom module, I have this function with this logic implemented:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'myform':
      drupal_set_message('this message is printed :D');
      $form['#validate'] = array('my_validation_function');
    break;
  }        
}

function my_validation_function($form, &$form_state) {

  drupal_set_message('not printed :(');
  watchdog('not printed :___(', 'not printed :___(');

}
```

I don't know exactly how it works but It seems that the second function is never called when I submit the form.

**EDIT (SOLUTION):**

I've finally found where the validation was placed in the module:

```
$form['mod_name']['submit']['#validate'][] = 'my_validation_function';
```

I thought that just adding form['#validate'] would work despite of the contents on $form variable, but seems that depending on the implementation of the module if you don't place the #validate element where it is expected it is ignored.

Comment: Have you tried passing the validate function without the array? `$form['#validate'] = 'my_validation_function';`

Comment: @DrColossos I've tried it but still no luck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be careful of replacing the #validate key as you will replace any other validators that have been added before you.

Best to append your function to it;

```
$form['#validate'][] = 'my_validation_function';
```

Comment: +1 for the tip but it is not working yet. Any idea on how can I track it better? Or some other way to implement the validation? Thank you.

Comment: It should work. Do you see your debug messages? Try to clear your cache, but I don't think it's a cache issue. Put die() in your validator :)